# How to make php work forever without cron?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Is there a way to make php work forever without cron.
What I want it for is to unban users after a few hours by running a mysql query, thanks

Comment: Anything particularly wrong with a cron job?

Comment: yeah, my provider doesn't support cron jobs, I heard that wordpress's admin folder has a ajax handler file that runs forever and executes wordpress cron functions

Comment: If they don't support cron jobs - then how would you run a script? What would run it?

Comment: I want a scrip to run automatically whenever a page of the script is visited, I also dont want duplicate processes of the script, want to use it to remove users from ban list after a fixed time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have access to cron jobs on your server (I guess you are running on a shared hosting?), the best alternative is to run an "external cron". Have a look at [www.setcronjob.com](http://www.setcronjob.com). I have been using this for a couple of months now and it is pretty stable.

1. You can set it up such that it calls a script on your website every whenever you want. (Example: http://www.yoursite.com/script.xxx)
2. In the script, you can run a MySQL query to check which users have been banned for a couple of hours and then unban them.

Comment: I need a service trust worthy, cause I have got real important data.

Comment: Don't think they have an API. And yes, that's the only catch, monthly renewal. I haven't come across any other reliable alternatives.

Comment: I mean there are other similar services, but, this one seems to be the most reliable.

Comment: can you please do a vote up for my question as I can not ask any questions anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You can start your script from the command line and let it run in the background. You will have to design this script in such a way that it never exits and just loops forever using the `sleep()` function to avoid unnecessary processor load. Since php scripts invoked from the command line have no max execution time the script will run until you manually kill it off with the `kill` command.

Once you've written the script you can start it with:

```
nohup php myscript.php &
```

`nohup` makes the script still run once you log out of the console session that you started it from, otherwise it would kill off then. The `&` symbol at the end starts the script as a new process in the background so that you can continue using the console.

Comment: Won't it be killed right after you terminate your ssh session?

Comment: @zerkms That's what `nohup` is for. It sets the process to ignore the `hangup` signal sent when the SSH session is closed so that it continues to run. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup